# Who can use Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am curious to know this after I contacted sales and sales asked me for additional information about my website. If everyone can use it, sales would not ask me that since it is pay per use. However, the website does not mention any minimum requirement or requirements in order to use the services.

So, I would like to confirm that is there any requirements (including minimum spendings and deposits)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that sales will ask you for more information in order to assist you in determining if this is the right product for you and if it would be able to do what you expect it to. They tend to help get you started.

There are no requirements or special prerequisites to use the service. You can visit https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/signup for details on how to get started, sign up and guidance on both the command line and web UI options for interacting with the service.

Comment: The $300 free trial must be used within 60 days, even though there is still remaining money, $300 will be expired?

Comment: You are correct, the trial ends once 60 days have elapsed or you've spent $300. You can visit https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/#FAQ for more information.

Comment: The FAQ does not answer this question but you answered here.